# Is it possible to create a dependent drop down list using poi excel purely

Tags: java, apache-poi

The first cell is a drop down list of 1,2,3,4, and the expected second cell is a drop down list of the numbers greater than the value of first cell and less than
 or equal to 4.

I got some intuitions from [Dependent Drop Down Lists in DataValidation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Validation) as follows:

```
  CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 1, 1);
  DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = 
  dvHelper.createFormulaListConstraint("INDIRECT(UPPER($A$1))");
  DataValidation validation =dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
  sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

and the key part of this trick is to give the list formula explicitly at `dvHelper.createFormulaListConstraint("INDIRECT(UPPER($A$1))")`

It is ok if I hard coded the list formula as follows:
`dvHelper.createFormulaListConstraint("$A$1:$A$4")`

but does not work when creating the list formula dynamicly
`CONCATENATE(ADDRESS($B$1,1), ":$A$4")`

and CONCATENATE directly neither
`CONCATENATE("$A$1", ":$A$4")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using a hidden sheet which stores the list values for the list constraints. And then named ranges for usage as list constraints in data validation.

One of the named ranges then can contain `INDEX` formula which gets a part of the list values dependent of the already selected value in the cell left hand from the cell the name is used in.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

class CreateExcelDependentDataValidationLists {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();  

   //hidden sheet for list values
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("ListSheet");
   sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("SourceList");
   int r = 1;
   for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    sheet.createRow(r++).createCell(0).setCellValue(i);
   }
   //unselect that sheet because we will hide it later
   sheet.setSelected(false);

   //visible data sheet
   sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

   //names for the list constraints
   Name namedCell = workbook.createName();
   namedCell.setNameName("List1To4");
   String reference = "ListSheet!$A$2:$A$5"; //List 1 to 4
   namedCell.setRefersToFormula(reference);

   namedCell = workbook.createName();
   namedCell.setNameName("ListLeftCellTo4");
   reference = "INDEX(List1To4,INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1000,ROW(),COLUMN()-1)):INDEX(List1To4,4)"; //List n to 4
                //List1To4Position=ThisRow.ThisColumn-1 : List1To4LastPosition
   namedCell.setRefersToFormula(reference);

   sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("1 to 4");
   sheet.getRow(0).createCell(1).setCellValue("n to 4");

   sheet.setActiveCell(new CellAddress("A2"));

   sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
   sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

   //data validations
   DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
   DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createFormulaListConstraint("List1To4");
   CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, 1, 0, 0);            
   DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);

   sheet.addValidationData(validation);

   dvConstraint = dvHelper.createFormulaListConstraint("ListLeftCellTo4");
   addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, 1, 1, 1);            
   validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);

   sheet.addValidationData(validation);

   //hide the ListSheet
   workbook.setSheetHidden(0, true);
   //set Sheet1 active
   workbook.setActiveSheet(1);

   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDependentDataValidationLists.xlsx");
   workbook.write(out);
   workbook.close();
   out.close();

 }
}
```